# np.mean(y_pred == y_test)の意味

Tags: python

```
np.mean(y_pred == y_test)
```

上のnp.meanが算術平均ということはわかったんですが＝＝はどういう意味になりますか？

Answer (score 2):

`y_pred == y_test` は、y_pred配列とy_test配列での要素毎の比較を行い、同サイズのboolean配列を返します。

> y_predとy_testのサイズが同じ場合に限ります

`np.mean()`は、`axis`を指定しないときは全ての要素の平均をとりますので、
`np.mean(y_pred == y_test)`は上記の２つの配列を比較したboolean配列の平均を取ることになります。
この際 `true`は`1`、`false`は`0`として計算されますので、結果２つの配列を比較して`要素が一致している確立`が算出されます。